# Calculating the power spectral density on a different bandwidth

Tags: power-spectral-density, bandwidth, signal-power

Let us say I have the power spectral density for a given bandwidth F1 at a transmit power T. I would like to calculate the power spectral density for bandwidth F2 for 1) the same transmit power T 
2) for different transmit power T2

How can I calculate this

For ex: Let's say I am looking at the spectrum of an OFDM signal in the baseband with a BW of 20Mhz transmitting at power of 23dbm and i know the power spectrum of this signal. Now I would like to derive the power spectrum of the OFDM baseband signal with a BW of 10MHz transmitted at the same power

Comment: The spectral density in different frequencies is orthogonal (no relation between one to another). Consider x= a*sin(t) + b*sin(5t). Knowing 'a' does not help you finding 'b'.

Comment: I am not referring to a different frequency but a different bandwidth on the same center frequency

Comment: Say in the first bandwidth the angular frequency of 5 was out of the bandwidth and in the second bandwidth it is in...

Comment: Let's say I am looking at the spectrum of an OFDM signal in the baseband with a BW of 20Mhz transmitting at power of 23dbm and i know the power spectrum of this signal. Now I would like to derive the power spectrum of the OFDM baseband signal with a BW of 10MHz transmitted at the same power, do you suggest this is not derivable?

Comment: No, I suggest putting all this newly presented information into the question.